# unlock column in protected sheet in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
ActiveSheet.Protect "RS"
ActiveSheet.Range("B:C").Locked = False
End Sub
```

I am trying above code but not working, i want to unlock only B and C column

Comment: What is the effect of the above code? "Not working" is not a very clear description. Is nothing locked? Is nothing unlocked?

Answer (score 4):

You are protecting the sheet before you unlock the range. But since the sheet is protected, the range cannot be unlocked. Swap the two lines and the code will work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
ActiveSheet.Range("B:C").Locked = False ' unlock the cells, so they can be edited in a protected sheet
ActiveSheet.Protect "RS" ' protect the sheet so only unlocked cells can be edited
End Sub
```

Comment: runtime error is occured, "enable to set locked property of the range class" during sheet selection

Comment: Well, the first time you run the code it locks the sheet. You have chosen to put the code into the Worksheet Activate module. So the next time the worksheet is activated (remember, it is already protected), the code tries to unlock some cells, which will fail, because the sheet is protected. In short: you need to get your code logic straightened out before you start coding. Don't just put code in and then see what happens. Make a plan first. It usually helps.

Comment: problem is solved, i am writing above code in workbook activate event, the working fine         `Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

Worksheets("ObjectDescriptionMapping").Range("B:C").Locked = False ' unlock the cells, so they can be edited in a protected sheet
Worksheets("ObjectDescriptionMapping").Protect "RS"

End Sub
 `

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

Worksheets("ObjectDescriptionMapping").Range("B:C").Locked = False ' unlock the cells, so they can be edited in a protected sheet
Worksheets("ObjectDescriptionMapping").Protect "RS"

End Sub
```